# ESQL convert date format

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Given this date format

```
2019-12-10 16:34:20
```

How to convert it into `2019-12-30T17:32:28Z`. In ESQL.

Comment: What did you try? What was the result?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
DECLARE inputStringDate CHARACTER '2019-12-10 16:34:20'
DECLARE outputStringDate CHARACTER ''
DECLARE date TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE patternInput CHARACTER 'yyyy-MM-dd'' ''HH:mm:ss';
DECLARE patternOutput CHARACTER 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss'Z'';

SET date = CAST(inputStringDate AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT patternInput);
SET outputStringDate = CAST(date AS CHARACTER FORMAT patternOutput);
```